# Deleting duplicates in a time series

Tags: sql-server, duplicates, time-series, sql-delete

I have a large set of measurements taken every 1 millisecond stored in a SQL Server 2012 table. Whenever there are 3 or more duplicate values in some rows that I would like to delete the middle duplicates. Highlighted values in this image of sample data are the ones that I want to delete. Is there a way to do this with a SQL query?

[image: SampleData]

Comment: Can you tell us the version of SQL Server? This tells us whether windowing functions are an option

Comment: It says SQL 2012 in the question. I'm very interested to see how these would work (I've never used them).

Comment: The server version is 2012 Express.

Comment: Do you truly want to delete them or just compress the ranges of duplicate measurement to the min and max observed time? I'm not a scientist, but it seems that deleting data is a bad idea.

Comment: Yes, I want to delete the duplicate middle values. It only takes to points to draw a line - extra points in the middle add no value.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this using a `CTE` and `ROW_NUMBER`:

[**SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/43e8e/3/0)

```
WITH CteGroup AS(
    SELECT *,
        grp = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY MS) - ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Value ORDER BY MS)
    FROM YourTable
),
CteFinal AS(
    SELECT *,
        RN_FIRST = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY grp, Value ORDER BY MS),
        RN_LAST  = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY grp, Value ORDER BY MS DESC)
    FROM CteGroup
)
DELETE 
FROM CteFinal 
WHERE
    RN_FIRST > 1
    AND RN_LAST > 1
```

Comment: This almost works. But, if a data point is preceded and followed by equal values it is deleted. Example, 20,20,40,20,20 - the 40 is being deleted when it should not be. I tried changing the where clause to "LG=LD and LG=Value" but this didn't seem to work correctly.

Comment: I suspect here should be `WHERE
    RN_FIRST <>  1
    AND RN_LAST <> 1 `

Comment: @GiorgiNakeuri, I believe `>` will suffice since `ROW_NUMBER` starts from `1`, or am I missing something?

Comment: @wewesthemenace, yes it is the same because rns are positive. Sorry.

Comment: Looks like this now works perfectly. Can you please explain how or point me to a good place to learn about CTE and partition? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I'm sure there must be a more efficient way to do this, but you could join the table to itself twice to find the previous and next value in the list, and then delete all of the entries where all three values are the same.

```
DELETE FROM tbl
WHERE ms IN
(
  SELECT T.ms
  FROM tbl T
  INNER JOIN tbl T1 ON T.ms = T1.ms + 1
  INNER JOIN tbl T2 ON T.ms = T2.ms - 1
  WHERE T.value = T1.value AND T.value = T2.value
)
```

If the table is really big, I can see this blowing tempdb though.

Answer (score 0):

Yes there is

```
 select * from table group by table.field ->value
```

Comment: this does not account for the order of the values.